# Is dataset.readxml(string) synchronous?

Tags: .net, windows-services, startup

I'm asking that because I created a windows service and it seem that under heavy load(which in my case when windows is booting up) the data inside the xml doesn't get loaded before I manually do stuff with it in my case is checking how many row are in a specific datatable inside that dataset.

Dataset got a schema.

Speudo code would be:

```vb
dataset.readxml("c:\myfile.xml")
if dataset.datatable1.rowcount is 1 
    do something
else
    do something else
```

In my case, it reach the else case even if there is one row.

If I start the service manually after, because the else case stop it, everything work fine.

---

If it's synchronous, what could cause that behavior?

Comment: My problem was a system.timers before that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous methods in the .NET classes follows the the BeginSomeAction() / EndSomeAction() pattern, so my guess is that ReadXml() is synchronous. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset_members.aspx) there's no BeginReadXml for DataSet.

EDIT: A quick browse through the implementation indicates a synchronous read, so unless there's something I have missed it supports my guess.